# How do I know if I have successfully created a table (Python, Psycopg2)?

Tags: python, psycopg

I've looked at the documentations but haven't found anything that lets me know if the last command i've execute via cursor.execute("...") is successful.

I'm expecting a reply like "1 row affected."

Comment: you could use a for loop, I suppose... to check if it was affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect some kind of [exception to be risen](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/errorcodes.html).
If everything went ok – the error code is [00000](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE) and no exception will get risen.

In `create table` case, you can always [double check](http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/errorcodes.html#psycopg2.errorcodes.lookup):

```
try:
    cur.execute("SELECT ouch FROM aargh;")
except Exception, e:
    pass

errorcodes.lookup(e.pgcode[:2])
# 'CLASS_SYNTAX_ERROR_OR_ACCESS_RULE_VIOLATION'
errorcodes.lookup(e.pgcode)
# 'UNDEFINED_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but one way to check for a successful operation with `psycopg2` is simply to look at the `rowcount` attribute for the cursor after your statement. This attribute returns the number of rows affected by the last `execute` statement.

e.g.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname="foo",user="postgres")
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s, %s)", (1,2))
cur.rowcount # returns 1
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM foo")
cur.rowcount # returns 0
```

A similar attribute is `statusmessage`, which returns a string including the type of the last operation performed along with the number of rows affected.

Comment: The similar attribute is actually `statusmessage`. The documentation is [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html)