# Python printing out SQL statement results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this following python code with pymysql

```
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select count(distinct `session_id`) from innodb.fh where `cs-uri-stem` like "/detail%"   """)
    cursor.fetchone()
```

which is working fine. But i just wonder how to print out the result for my sql statement. it should print out 1204. I tried the following but it is not working:

```
       results = cursor.execute("""select count(distinct `session_id`) from innodb.fh where `cs-uri-stem` like "/detail%"   """)
       print (results)
```

thx!

Comment: What are you triyng to extract? Will fetchall() do any good?

Comment: probably i did not explain my questions clearly. The sql statement in my code would return "1204" as the result. But i just wonder how I could print out this 1204 thing in python

Comment: If you're trying to get the number of rows affected when you do `cursor.execute()`, note that this depends on the database connector you are using. For Postgres with psycopg2, for example you can use [`cursor.rowcount`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222256/how-do-i-know-if-i-have-successfully-created-a-table-python-psycopg2/36146253#36146253).

Comment: So clarify. What database connector software are you using? PyMySQL? Psycopg2? More simply: what library are you using to get `cursor` from?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan hi, i used pymysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PyMySQL` cursor defines an attribute called `rowcount`, as can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/cursors.py).

Immediately after `cursor.execute()`, you can call `cursor.rowcount` to get the number of rows affected by the SQL statement.